# Unable to write request.getParameter() into jsp from servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am sending html table containing data from servlet to my jsp page. My servlet code is following:

```
String html = "<table><thead><th>Serial</th><th>MAC</th></thead>"
              + "<tbody>
              + "<tr>1000234<td></td><td>9845HM98</td></tr>"
              + "<tbody>"
              + "</table>";

request.setAttribute("responselDetails", html);

ServletContext context= getServletContext();
RequestDispatcher rd= context.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/Details.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

jsp:

```
<% if (request.getParameter("responsePeripheralDetails") != null) { %>
<%= request.getParameter("responsePeripheralDetails") %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Please explain what type of error you are getting

Comment: give no exception or error but not printing anything... Answer by @David sovled my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you mixed `request.setParameter()` and `request.setAttribute()`

You are setting `request.setAttribute()` in servlet and trying to access it via `request.getParameter()` in jsp which always give exception of nullPointer.

quick fix: correct `getParameter()` to `getAttribute()` in jsp and you are done :-)

```
<% if (request.getAttribute("responsePeripheralDetails") != null) { %>
<%= request.getAttribute("responsePeripheralDetails") %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Oh I missed this little thing. Thanks for saving my life